# Laravel Rate Limiter Release time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I am using a custom rate limiter as per https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#rate-limiting.

```php
// App Service Provider
RateLimiter::for('google-sheets', function (object $job) {
    return Limit::perMinute(20);
});
```

```php
// Job
public function middleware(): array
{
    return [
        new RateLimitedWithRedis('google-sheets')
    ];
}

public function retryUntil(): \DateTime
{
    return now()->addMinutes(10);
}
```

The rate limiter is working, and it is releasing jobs back into the queue, however, it appears to be cycling them back into the queue very fast, to the point where my RDS IOPS is tripping out!

Is there any way to set the release time longer on this? I want to set a 5-second release time, which is possible with something like the spatie middleware:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-rate-limited-job-middleware

```php
// Job
public function middleware()
{
    $rateLimitedMiddleware = (new RateLimited())
        ->allow(30)
        ->everySeconds(60)
        ->releaseAfterSeconds(90);

    return [$rateLimitedMiddleware];
}
```